# htaccess redirects to blank page issue (Core PHP)

Tags: php, .htaccess

Whenever I click one of the news listings, I am redirected to a blank page. But when clicking on the browser URL and pressing enter loads my page correctly.
My htaccess:

```
# Apache search queries statistic module
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}(google|yahoo|aol|bing|crawl|aspseek|icio|bot|spider|nutch|slurp|seznam|Seznam) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (google|aol|yahoo|msn|search|bing|Seznam|seznam)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (pdf|php|html)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !common.php
RewriteCond /home/testcode/public_html/common.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /common.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Satisfy Any

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#News redirect code
RewriteRule ^news/([^/\.]+)(\.html)?$  news_page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Example of the news listing URL
http://testcode.com/news/34

Note: news_page.php is news detail page which I am getting blank.

Any kind of help on this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is likely caching the htaccess file changes. Try it in a different browser, or close and reopen your current browser